# Code breaks after anwser with a dot and skips the rest of the code

Tags: c++, for-loop

If i don't use dots like 1.5 it will break but if it's whole number like 15 it works perfectly

I tried to looking for it in the internet but didn't find the fix it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,sk,i,a,p,b,c;
    int kiek=0;
    cout << "insert how many shops did he went to" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    b=n;
    cout << "how many thing did he buy in every shop" << endl;
    cin >> p;
    c=p;

   for(int n=0; b>n; n++)
    {
    a=0;
    for (int i=1; i<=c; i++)
    {
        cout << "insert "<< i << " product price"<< endl;
        cin >> sk;
        a=a+sk;
        }
          cout<< "spent " << a<< " pmoney"<< endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

it should let me type how much did he spent with every product but if i add a . it skips everything and shows only one

Comment: i use 3 for shops and 5 for the ammount

Comment: int can't store decimal points. use double or float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

An integer type cannot store decimal values.

When you execute `int sk; cin >> sk;` and you enter "1.5", the `operator >>` will store 1 in `sk` and leave `.5` in the stream. The next time you execute `cin >> sk`, the stream will try to read the next integer with what is left in the stream, but will fail because "." cannot be converted to an integer, leaving your stream in a 'fail' state. For this point, all `cin` instructions will fail to read the next integer.

**Solution**

To fix the problem, I suggest to declare price values as doubles: `double a,sk`. However, the same problem will occur if you enter an invalid floating point value. I strongly suggest to correctly manage stream errors and react accordingly. You can access the state using [`rdstate()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdstate/) or its related methods (good, fail, bad, eof).